# How to use a regex pattern to remove a piece of code from an HTML page?

Tags: java, html, regex, string

I am extracting some information from a website.

Unfortunately, the code isn't very organized and some pieces of code (XML and Styles) appear in the middle of the HTML structure.

I put all the HTML code in a string using Java and I want to get rid of things like these:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
```

(This code appears in one part of the page...)

Or more complex ones, like this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
   <w:DontFlipMirrorIndents/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="267">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="37" Name="Bibliography"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" QFormat="true" Name="TOC Heading"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin-top:0in;
    mso-para-margin-right:0in;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    mso-para-margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Which appears also on the same page.

I noticed the if and endif tags so I tried to use the replaceall function to remove every part of the string that contains that pattern.

I am using the following pattern:
`html = html.replaceAll("(<!--(.*)-->)*?", "");`

I also tried this:
`html = html.replaceAll("(<!--(.*)-->)", "");`
`html = html.replaceAll("(<!--(.*)<!\\[endif\\]-->)", "");`

They are pretty vague, but every other variation I have tried don't work at all.

Unfortunately these don't work either since they only remove the first one but the large one remains there...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use a HTML parser to do this.

Comment: I extracted all the information, I just need to clean up the data I got, and the only problem is I can't remove those if, endif blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your regex to match also the line breaks.

```
html = html.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", "");
```